# GO AWS SDKv2: Parsing json file and adding values as tags for AWS Secretsmanager

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

I have the requirement to write a cross-platform cli tool in go by leveraging the AWS SDKv2 GO.

I need to parse a json file like this:

```json
{
    "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "global1",
                    "Value": "val1"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "global2",
                    "Value": "val2"
                }
              ]
}
```

I have this function:

```golang
package lib

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/secretsmanager"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)
//func CreateSecret(client *secretsmanager.Client, secretName string, description string, kmsKeyId string, secretString string) {
func CreateSecret(client *secretsmanager.Client) {

    // Parse tags.json
    jsonFile, err := os.Open("tags.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    // defer the closing of our jsonFile so that we can parse it later on
    defer jsonFile.Close()

    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)

    tags := []*secretsmanager.Tag{}
    json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &tags)
    
   // rest of the code is truncated...
}
```

However, I receive this error:

lib/commands.go:58:28: undefined: secretsmanager.Tag

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`secretsmanager.Tag` does not exist. But what I think you are looking for is this package: `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/secretsmanager/types`. Import it and then you will have `types.Tag`, which is what you probably need.